# AVD not working AMD A8 5545

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have a new laptop:
AMD A8  5545 with Radeon HD Graphic 1.70 GH - 8 GB Ram - 64 Bit

When I tried to Run AVD in Android Studio:
Nexus S API 24 , Android 7.0 - X86

I found the following Error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you won't be able to run the emulator without HAXM enabled. (which is not supported by your system).

As stated on the Android Site;

> Many modern CPUs provide extensions for running virtual machines (VMs)
>   more efficiently. Taking advantage of these extensions with the
>   Android emulator requires some additional configuration of your
>   development system, but can significantly improve the execution speed.
>   Before attempting to use this type of acceleration, you should first
>   determine if your development system’s CPU supports one of the
>   following virtualization extensions technologies:
>
> Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
>
> > AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)

My suggestion would be to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) as an alternative which works exceedingly well as compared to the default emulator shipped with Android Studio or switch to a Linux based distro.

Comment: Thanks That I'll do it If no answer help me

Comment: If I Download a new Emulator with ARM can it run or not ? what's the different?

Comment: ARM emulators are considerably slower as compared to the newer x86 emulators which are over 10 times faster.
While there is a chance that the arm system image will work, but it's slow speed will make debugging quite hard.